# What happens when a military token is placed on a conquered location during a Competitive game?

Tags: conquest-of-planet-earth

Conquest of Planet Earth is an homage to every bad science fiction movie: bug-eyed aliens are trying to take over Earth, ostensibly because their Overlords said so. (Personally, I think it's just that [Mars Needs Women](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MarsNeedsWomen), or possibly [Mars Needs After-Dinner Mints](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlueAndOrangeMorality).) You play as the aliens, crushing the Hunam resistance and conquering various bits of the planet.

During the game, various events can place tokens belonging to the human military on top of locations. Because the Random Number God hates you, those tokens can appear on top of places that you've already conquered, but don't have any units in.

**What happens when a Hunam military token lands on a location you've conquered?** I couldn't find any rules stating that the location is un-conquered. There's rules about starting a combat immediately if you have a unit there (which might kill the alien), but nothing about changing the state of conquest if you lose the combat. The battle rules make the implicit assumption that the aliens are invading the human space.

(As a side note, there *are* rules for Resistance Counters un-conquering Locations, but only in the Cooperative game where the aliens work together and the Hunam Resistance is weak. In the Competitive game, where the aliens are competing to get to 8 victory points first, there aren't any rules for this. The Cooperative rules are explicitly *not* part of the Competitive rules.)

Comment: Since this is a silly game, and you wrote it twice, I'm not actually sure: is "Hunam" a typo?

Comment: Technically, yes (the game calls 'em humans), but I rather liked Star Control II, and that's what the Spathi called the, er, inhabitants of Earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Conquest Marker remains**

You couldn't find any rules about unconquering the location, because you do not do so. This is supported by several rules in the [rulebook](http://www.flyingfrog.net/conquestofplanetearth/pdf%5CCOPE_Rulebook_Web.pdf). Page 16, under **Resistance Counters**

> Occasionally a card will call for one or more Resistance Counters to be placed onto the board. [...]
>
> **Moving Into a Space with Resistance Counters**
>
> If you move Aliens onto a Space with one or more Resistance Counters, you will need to Fight those Resistance Counters during your Battle Phase in addition to the normal Resistance drawn for that Location. **If the Location has already been conquered (and has a Conquest Marker on it), you must still fight the Resistance Counters.**

So, nothing happens to your Conquest Marker, but if you or an opponent enter the Location they will have to fight the Resistance Token. This is further supported by the rules for stealing Terror Points from an opponent, replacing their Conquest Marker with your own, on page 17 under:

> **Stealing Conquests**
>
> **If a player ever has one or more Aliens in a Location with an opponent’s Conquest Marker during their own Battle Phase (and there are no enemies present)**, that player may simply replace the opponent’s Conquest Marker with their own, **stealing the glory and the Terror Points for themselves**. Note that this swap of markers only happens during your Battle Phase and **only if there are no enemies** currently at that Location (Alien **or Resistance**). Also note that this only happens in the Battle Phase, so simply moving through a Location with another player’s Conquest Marker during your Action Phase will NOT swap it for your own.